# Glitchy animation is driving me insane, please help

Tags: animation

I'm new here and fairly new to blender. Amazing software.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3afhi.gif

As you can see from the gif, I encountered a problem animating my scene and I spent most of the day trying to figure out what causes it and how to fix it with no luck. What bothers me the most is that everything works as expected except those two vertical moves, whereas the outcomes are correct but the animation gets glitchy.
Do you guys have any idea why? I leave the link to the blender file in case you feel brave enough to give it a try --> https://we.tl/t-AwTSGAwhvW

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are experiencing something like gimbal lock due to the repeated rotation.  If you just pick one of the cubes (3faced.001) you can see it rotates from <0, 0, -180> to <180, -90, 0> on frames 72-78. Blender has to try to figure out how to interpolate between those values and chooses a mathematical route, which doesn't necessarily match the best visual.

The easiest fix is adding more keyframes - if you add keys on the frames in between it should fix the rotations.

A possibly better fix would be to rotate/keyframe using Quaternion instead of Euler XYZ.  You could also possibly try 'Apply Rotation' periodically so your rotations don't cross the 180 degree line.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried to switch rotation mode but quaternion and any other didn't fix the problem in my case, same goes for periodically applying rotation. Although it was helpful to learn that the issue is pretty common and known with the name "gimbal lock." By googling it I reached a tutorial explaining every possible way to work around it, to me was baking the action to an empty and then back to the object for every single broken cube. I'll leave the link in case somebody else needs it --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETRVoI3nBbM

Comment: Sorry, I was going to put images and more detailed explanations here but something came up so I had to cut it short. Glad you were able to find a solution!